# Drupal Not Diplaying pictures When changing directory

Tags: drupal

I'm new to drupal. After I style my webpage. when I go to /user or any other directory, the styling and picture disappear. However, if I use view and create a view I am able see everything correctly. Do you know the reason why?

Comment: hey Luis! think you'll have to share a bit more of what you've done and what you're experiencing so we're able to help.. where have you done the styling? where is it working? what do you mean by using a view? the more you can share the more people will be able to help you out..

Comment: Alberto, I totally agree with you, but the original post isn't mine, but from iTsFILIP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have your images in the correct directory.